# how to make a POST request via async call in NodeJs

Tags: node.js

I have the following route

**route**

```
{
    method: "POST",
    path: "/g/{gId}/exchange",
    config: {
      handler: eHandler ,
    }
  },
```

**my handler**

```
const { pExchange } = require("../lib/gStore");

const eHandler = async (req, h) => {
  if(req.payload.card === undefined){
    return h.response("...").code(202);
  }
  if(req.params.gId === undefined){
    return h.response("...").code(202);
  }
  if (!pExchange (req.params.gId,req.state.player)) {
    return h.response("...").code(202);
  }

  return h.response("OK");
};

module.exports = eHandler ;
```

I want to make this into a post request so the response is in an ajax call and not redirecting me to a blank page with the result.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const { pExchange } = require("../lib/gStore");

const eHandler = async (req, h) => {

let pExchangeValue = await pExchange(req.params.gId,req.state.player);

  if(req.payload.card === undefined){
    return h.response("...").code(202);
  }
  if(req.params.gId === undefined){
    return h.response("...").code(202);
  }
  if (!pExchangeValue) {
    return h.response("...").code(202);
  }

  return h.response("OK");
};

module.exports = eHandler ;
```